# Java path..Error of jvm.cfg

Tags: java

Can anyone please tell me why I get the following error when I try to run my Java programs? The programs get compiled successfully but are not able to be run.  I have already set the path of Java.

```
C:\JavaServ>javac hello1.java
C:\JavaServ>java hello1
Error: could not open C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg
```

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:java-ee]?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

this should be an internal file of JRE and in general you shouldn't deal with it when you're running/compiling java.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190360/what-is-the-purpose-of-jvm-cfg-file-in-relation-to-java) you can find an explanation of what exactly this file is intended for.
Bottom line, your Java installation is somehow corrupted, so as a first resort to resolve this issue, I suggest you to re-install jre.

You should ensure that you're installing the right jre for your architecture.

Hope, this helps

Comment: If you reinstall it's just going to search for this file in the JRE so it's stopping you from deleting the JRE.

Comment: NOT useful. If there's something wrong that I _can_ fix, I'm visiting SO to find out what it IS, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 26):

Don't think if this is a correct way...(perhaps proper installation of Java is a permanent solution)....but this is a trick..:)

Delete the “java.exe” file from “c:\windows” and “c:\windows\system32″. That should fix it.

Comment: If you instaled jdk and jre in separete packages and then deleted one of them - that trik will work

Comment: what about javaws.exe ?, should I remove that ?

Comment: @Francisco Corrales: No need to remove javaws

Comment: It works for me, simply search for "Java" in "c:\windows" and delete every "java.exe", "javaw.exe", "javaws.exe"

Comment: Those files dont exsist

Comment: Sometimes you have also to delete it from `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`.

Comment: I really  dont see how deleting random files from windows for no reason is a solution to anything

Answer (score 19):

In case you get here and scroll this far down, the newer Oracle versions of Java x86 and probably also x64 are horribly broken.  You may find that after removing all versions of Java, and even manually deleting all the versions you find in c:/program files/ and c:/program files (x86)/ that you still can't properly run a fresh install of Java.

I'm here to tell you why, and how to fix it.

Go to C:\Program Files\Common Files\ and DELETE the Oracle directory.  It has a version of Java underneath it inside a junction (symlink) that is sequestered away from all your other installs.  Bastards.

Now, also go to System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables and edit the PATH under System Variables.  Find the place where the Oracle folder is referenced, and delete it.  Close all your windows down, reboot to be extra sure if you want.

Install the JRE or JDK.  Open a command prompt and type 'java' and if it comes up, you're golden.  If not, go back to the PATH variable and add "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin" or whatever looks right for your machine.

I hate Oracle.

Comment: Exactly. Can also be the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java`. Furthermore, make sure that `JAVA_HOME` is still set correctly.

Comment: Yes, I had to delete `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java` and also remove it from system PATH

Comment: The Oracle comment is quite to the point (+1)

Answer (score 6):

You can not Uninstall/Reinstall JRE if you are having this error. 
That's why because previous installation has copied 3 files namely Java.exe, Javaw.exe, javaws.exe in the c:/windows/system32 folder.
Simply go there and remove these files and download a fresh version of jre from oracle and install it. I will prefer JDK 1.6 update 45. Which is very stable.

Answer (score 5):

[update registry path to installation location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy4hh.jpg)

This happened for me when I moved out my default installation from an overcrowded primary partition to another location. Fir

Answer (score 3):

Java mysteriously broke on my work PC after a security patch was pushed out to us, giving this error whenever you tried to run a Java program.  Somehow the 'lib' subdirectory of the Java 7 install had vanished!  It might have been related to having multiple Java versions installed simultaneously.

If you're getting this error there are basically two things that could be wrong:

1) Your Java installation is broken.  If the file/directory it's complaining about doesn't exist, uninstall and reinstall the JRE and then it should be there.  This fixed it for me.

2) If the files are there, your PATH is somehow incorrect or pointing at an old/broken Java install.  In this case you either need to fix your PATH to point to the correct java.exe/javaw.exe, or use a fully qualified path.  So instead of:

```
java <whatever>
```

Use

```
c:\<full path to correct JRE>\bin\java.exe <whatever>
```

3) If your PATH is correct and files are there and it's still failing, the path could be getting truncated because it is too long.  see: [Running Java gives "Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036462/running-java-gives-error-could-not-open-c-program-files-java-jre6-lib-amd64) .

Comment: Uninstalling/reinstalling does not fix the issue. The amd64 folder is not being created, while the java.com version verifier verifies the latest version. Still, even simple command line `java -version` fails.

Answer (score 3):

i also had the same issue due to one more instance of `java,javaw` and `javaws` in `C:\Windows\System32` which was pointing to `jre6` and my default location of jre was pointing to this(C:\Windows\System32) location. Even having jdk 1.8 as my `JAVA_HOME` location i  were getting this problem.
so either remove or rename java,javaw and javaws it will work.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have installer deployed Java on Windows and decided to bring some order to your JDKs with folders moving...

All answers with `java.exe` in `Windows\System32` are right but in more tough situation - there are no files, but error messages still happen, then **remember** about *Windows Registry* entries (look `regedit.exe`).

They store information about JRE folder in this registry key:

win32:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment`

win64:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment`

Answer (score 1):

The program can be compiled but while running it leads to such an error:

> Could not open  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg

It indicates that the jvm.cfg file is missing in Program files. Reasons may be file corruption or file may be deleted. Install JRE again in "Program Files" folder.

Another case which happened with me is that I installed 32 bit jdk & jre in my 64 bit system in Program Files(x86) and my Program Files folder was empty. That was the reason for that error. So I installed 64 bit JRE in Program Files folder and it started to work. Note that it is not related to jdk version. Associated with only JRE problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error with my docear program on windows 7.

What I found is that I had two instances of java 1.6 installed on my computer. One instance has a jvm.cfg and the other does not.

Modifying my path to search the correct instance of java (in bold) first fixed the problem.

Here is my corrected path:

> C:\Users\kranjit>path
>   PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32
>   \WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\;**C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin**;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;

Answer (score 0):

In our system, for "java(jre)" for runtime purpose is availed, So If you install any different version of java, propbably the version before the one which is already installed.

E.g.; my windows 8.1 I have runtime java version of 8, then when I install Ver7 it is bu default taking V8, yet I uninstall 8, In this kind of Scenarios, Removing java.exe from c:\windows\system32 makes my java runtime work

Answer (score 0):

- The simple Solution is just `uninstall` the `javaSE` and `reinstall` it to the default location.
- Then copy the installed location probably like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin`.
- After then go to desktop then while selecting right click on `My Pc or This pc shortcut` the under that select `properties >> Advanced system settings >> under Advance tab >> last option Environment Variables..>>path >> edit >> past >> ;`(not required if win10)/(required if windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having an issue I made mine work by doing this probably not the best fix but it worked for me..

I uninstalled all Java's that i current had installed, reinstalled the latest one and changed the install directory to C:/Windows/jre (Basically where it kept saying there was no config file)

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed more than one jdk version , uninstall the others and keep only the one in use. this worked for me. 
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/uninstall_java.xml

Answer (score 0):

I want to add some pointers here.

Whenever you face the error saying `Could not open jvm.cfg`, it means that there was some mess happened with `java installation path`. Below approaches might help.

1. If java is added in environment path, then open command prompt and type `where java`. If you get list of directories where java path specified. Other than the directory where you need the java file, delete the java files in all other directories.
2. If you are reading 2nd pointer, then 1st pointer might have not helped. Type `regedit` in run dialog and under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, go to `softwares/javasoft` and rename the paths of the java installed directory.

Let me know if above approaches solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when installing 201, somehow it didn't uninstall my 191 properly. I had to go to the Program Files/Java folder, rename the old 201 directory, then install a fresh copy of 201. When doing so, it prompted me to uninstall 191, which I did. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue after upgrading my java version.I had more than one jdk installation. I have manually uninstalled the old jdk version . Then it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

I had similar issue, I tried different things but nothing worked. Then when I checked the installed programs. I could see two versions of java installed.

> ***What I did is, just uninstall all java versions and freshly installed the required version. But this didn't seem to work when I checked in terminal. Then I had to reopen the terminal and run the command, then only it worked.***

Note : Dont forget to reopen the terminal if you are testing via terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had an identical error trying to start IntellJ with a custom JBR.

```
C:\Users\user>"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.3\bin\idea.bat"

Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.3\jbr-arm64\lib\jvm.cfg'
```

This issue may occur if there were problems extracting Java or OpenJDK from a zip or tarball (e.g. a slow extraction was terminated prematurely) or if the zip or tarball was corrupted or incomplete.

- If caused by a corrupted zip or tarball, try redownloading the archive.
- If caused by a bad extraction, repeating the extraction will fix this.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Error:could not open jvm.cfg]

Copying and pasting `i386\jvm.cfg` from a different PC will resolve the issue.

Comment: This isn't clear.  There are multiple **i386** directories and it's **amd64** in the 64-bit JRE.  The directory on 64-bit (x64) is **lib/amd64/jvm.cfg** (**jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg** in the JDK) and on 32-bit (x86) is **lib/i386/jvm.cfg** (**jre/lib/i386/jvm.cfg** in the JDK).

Comment: If the path is **WRONG**, it's never a good idea to just randomly copy a config file, I've learned this the _hard_ way from experience.

Answer (score -1):

It means that this `jvm.cfg` file is not found. Maybe it was deleted. `Reinstall` the program. If you have this problem with a game for example, `reinstall Java` in the games folder, or copy Java files `.de c:/Program Files/JAVA` and paste to the `JAVA` folder in the game folder

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue.I just uninstalled Java and reinstalled again it worked fine after that . The problem is related to JRE so you can just reinstall JRE.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem - when I tried to run a Java program from command line the error message appeared: "Error: could not open jvm.cfg".
My Path environment variable included following path:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

In the folder there were 3 exe files:

```
java.exe
javaw.exe
javaws.exe
```

When I removed the the entry

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

from the  Path environment variable and restarted cmd, I could run the program as usual (java MyProg).
Obviously I have corrupted the path pointing to correct java jre installation

`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151`

somehow previously when I played with my settings.