# Having troubles compiling Java programs

Tags: java

Sorry I couldn't be more specific with the question itself. Here's what I'm running: Windows 7 64bit, JDK v7, JRE v7 (64 bit), and JRE v6 (32 bit). I'm pretty new when it comes to Java, however I do know how to compile a program and all that stuff. I kept getting an error when I tried running my compiled programs:

```
C:\Users\Sean\Documents\JAVASTUFF\Chapter 3\1>javac ch3p1.java

C:\Users\Sean\Documents\JAVASTUFF\Chapter 3\1>java ch3p1
Error: could not open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\i386\jvm.c

C:\Users\Sean\Documents\JAVASTUFF\Chapter 3\1>java -cp ch3p1
Error: could not open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\i386\jvm.c

C:\Users\Sean\Documents\JAVASTUFF\Chapter 3\1>java cd3p1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cd3p1
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cd3p1
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: cd3p1.  Program will exit.

C:\Users\Sean\Documents\JAVASTUFF\Chapter 3\1>java -version
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

*note that it couldn't find the file because I had changed the folder name to see if it  would automatically detect the 64 bit JRE I have installed*

However, after enough searching I found a page that stated my problems were because I was running a program I compiled on JDK v7 in JREv6. I messed around with that for a little while, trying to get it to run in the JRE that came with my download of JDK.

```
CD: C:\Users\Sean\Documents\JAVASTUFF\Chapter 3\1
Current directory: C:\Users\Sean\Documents\JAVASTUFF\Chapter 3\1
javac ch3p1.java
Process started >>>
<<< Process finished.
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe ch3p1
Process started >>>
Error: Could not find or load main class ch3p1
<<< Process finished.
```

I'm using Notepad++ and NppExec to compile faster, and I gave up trying to get it to run JRE v7 and just used the location of it. And here's my NppExec code (I don't know if it's important, but I'll post it anyways):

```
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)

javac $(FILE_NAME)

C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe $(NAME_PART)
```

And, finally, here's the actual program I'm trying to get to run:

```
public class ch3p1
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.print("Hello.");
    }
}
```

So, a quick recap. The first error I found out was because I was compiling and running a program with different versions of JDK and JRE. I couldn't figure out how to actually make it run with the JRE that came with my JDK installation so I used the direct path to it instead. My hopes got crushed that this would work when I went to run my compiled program. I got a simple "Error: Could not find or load main class ch3p1".

What's the question? I don't know exactly, the broad question is: What do I need to do to get this to work? I cannot be any more descriptive than that because I have no idea what to do or where to look next. I'm hoping I provided enough useful information and structured it well enough to make it comprehensible.

Some other questions: Will removing the two Java 6 updates in my Add/Remove Programs work? How do I change it so whenever it runs java, it'll run the 64bit JRE v7?

I have no idea what I'm doing here and I'm basically learning as I go. I am familiar with computers to an extent but I am new to Java and JDK so I don't know much about how it works. My leads might be completely misdirected and wrong, if so, please correct me.

**EDIT**

I understand that there are a lot of questions on this website and I'm sure the people posting here answer a lot of questions that can be solved with minimal to no effort involved. I have to say that I have looked everywhere and I came here to post this because I simply cannot find the solution to my problem. I wasn't looking for help on finding another program to use, and I definitely was not putting the files in my Java installation directory because despite me being new to Java, I am not new to programming. That response could have been easily avoided by looking at the first example I provided, and another one where the file path to my .java and .class files can be seen in a folder in my Documents.

I will list answers and what I have tried here:

- I reinstalled JDK *and* JRE from the Oracle website
- I have set my SET_HOME system variable and my Path system variable has the JDK bin directory in it.
- My .class file and my .java file are in the same directory, and my class and the .java file are both named the same thing, including exact cases.
- After I installed JDK and JRE I deleted my previous files and made a new one, and that didn't work either.
- I tried putting the direct locations of java and javac as suggested in a reply.
- I realize that there are better IDE and build programs out there, I am using javac because the class I am in right now is using javac.

Now, for some extra questions to help me out:

- I have the Java v6.xx updates in my add/remove programs list, would removing these in any way effect anything in a positive or negative way. And would complete removal of all JDK/JRE files and re-installation change anything?
- Is there any known issues with using Java and Windows 7 that I might be running into.
- Is this an issue with JRE or JDK, because it seems to be compiling without any issues but when I go to run it is when I get the errors.
- Are there any other variables other than CLASS_PATH or Path that I need to set?

I appreciate any and all help that's been given so far even though I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with java by reading and doing some tutorials. Like this one http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html

Comment: Stop typing javac and learn to use ant, or maven, or some other actual build tool.

Comment: @bmargulies I think that beginners should start as simple as possible. Learning Maven before starting to program is probably too much and too confusing.

Comment: No, it is a good habit to learn javac before using Maven, Ant or Gradles or any other build tool

Comment: Post your code.  I'll make it work.

Comment: Ant?  Maven?  You're kidding me.  That's ludicrous.

Comment: The main clue in this case is the following only some characters got removed when you copied the question:
Error: could not open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\i386\jvm.c

I think you should see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051103/java-path-error-of-jvm-cfg which points to a corrupted installation.

The error you get is not due to code but from a bad java setup on your system. I'd suggest removing all versions of java, cleaning up, and re-installing. Also making sure everything is work with your environmental variables, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the absolute path to the directory where you installed java. Here is what I would type on my machine

```
cd "C:\Users\Sean\Documents\JAVASTUFF\Chapter 3\1"

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\javac" ch3p1.java

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\java" ch3p1
```

if that works, you should add the directory to the path so that this is the preffered java version. This way you won't have to use the absolute path anymore and just type "java" and "javac" as usual

```
set PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\";%PATH%
```

Setting the path can also be done somewhere in the Control Panel so that you don't have to type that in each time you open a command prompt

**Edit:** You should probably set JAVA_HOME as well as "duffymo" suggests. If it still doesnt work there may be something wrong with your java installation. Try downloading and installing a new version from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u2-download-1377129.html)

Comment: The second `javac` should be `java`, I presume?

Comment: @madth3 yes, I fixed the example now :-)

Comment: Should I use C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java? Or is there no difference between the two. How would I set JAVA_HOME? I saw that in an example somewhere but I don't see it in the system variables and I figured that it was set somewhere already but it wouldn't hurt to check. I'm not that familiar with console commands so I don't want to mess anything up. I'll look around for it and edit this if I can find anything. I'm sure I will.

Comment: I can't edit it again, still get the "Error: Could not find or load main class ch3p1" message when I set the JAVA_HOME system variable.

Comment: @Snhr Try installing a new version of JDK just in case. The versions of java you should use are found in the jdk1.7.xx\bin folder (just use my example where you replace the path to your newly installed version of java). I tested your example myself yesterday and it worked, so something must be wrong with your java version. Try to compile and run the program using the java/javac programs that are in the same directory.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error even if I use the java.exe in the JDK bin directory. I appreciate the help Optimist, it seems like you're the only one that actually replied with a relevant answer. I'll figure it out eventually, if not I'll just deal with it. I'm hoping to get a new hard drive sometime soon so maybe a fresh install of everything would help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by saying you should never, ever put any of your code in the directories where you installed Java JDK.  Please make it a habit to create a separate folder (e.g. "c:\work") and put your project sub-folders there.

Open a command shell and type this: `java -version`.  That will tell you the version of Java you're compiling and running with.  You care about the JDK, because you're developing code.

Is your JAVA_HOME environment variable set?  Please point it to the directory where you installed Java.  Then add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to your PATH.  If you do all this correctly, you should be able to compile in a command shell by typing `javac`.

So, create a folder `c:\work\learning\src` and put your `ch3p1.java` folder in it.  `Create a directory c:\work\learning\classes`, too.  Compile your code with this command:

```
javac -cp .;classes -d classes src\*.java
```

You should see ch3p1.class in the classes folder.

Run it with this command:

```
java -cp .;classes ch3p1
```

You'll see "Hello." in the console.

EDIT: I'd recommend that you read this tutorial carefully:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html

You aren't the first person to compile and run "hello world".  It seems to me that you're thrashing around too much.  Simplify.

Comment: From his examples it seems that he did the right thing and did not put the code inside the java installation directory but in a separate directory (C:\Users\Sean\Documents)

Answer (score -1):

Several things here.

Java compiler can take a "target" argument to indicate for which Java version you wish to compile. By default, the target is the version of the current JVM.

So far, any class compiled with a given target is compatible with that target and any above version. So a class compiled for Java 5 is compatible with Java 5, 6 and 7.

To find out which version of Java you are running, type java -version in your terminal. It will output something like "Java 1.X..." The 'X' is the version of Java and you will often see people talking about Java 5 or Java 1.5 which is the same thing (same goes for 6 and 7).

The version that is running depends on several parameters, but usually it all comes down to the first Java bin directory in your 'PATH' environment variable.

Now, if you are considering Java IDE, there are 3 major ones:

- Eclipse
- NetBeans
- IntelliJ

All three are fine Java IDE's and it is pretty much religious which one you will prefer. Personnally I use Eclipse.

Finally, for you problem:

1. Comiple using `javac ch3p1.java`
2. Run using `java -cp . ch3p1`

Comment: I would not recommend an IDE to anyone just starting out with Java.  Before an IDE you just don't know Java; the moment you add one to the mix you've got two problems.  At least become familiar with the process of compiling and running simple programs in a command shell and a text editor.  You'll understand CLASSPATH and appreciate what an IDE is doing for you.  And if I did I'd choose IntelliJ over either Eclipse or NetBeans.

Comment: Indeed it is a good habit to know the basics before jumping on an IDE. But since he was talking about tools, I thought I would give him a hint on what exists. Regarding the choice, as I said, it is religious, so let's just give him the choice instead of claiming one is better.

Comment: I actually typed -version in one of my examples, I'm compiling with JDK v7 and it's running it with JVM v6.xx. It's not a problem with compiling with an older version than my runtime environment, it's a problem with compiling on a newer version than my runtime environment. And I don't like using IDEs for most things. I just use Notepad++.

Comment: No - run and compile with the same JVM would be my recommendation.

Comment: It's always his choice.  My opinion doesn't take the choice away any more than yours does.  Mine is based on experience with all of them, but that's beside the point.

Comment: It doesn't work when I compile on the same version either but it's a different error.