# Having difficulties in Java. Beginner here

Tags: windows, path, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java path..Error of jvm.cfg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051103/java-path-error-of-jvm-cfg)

When I type in Java in cmd it pops out this error

Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg

I tried this method from googling but the same error happen again. 
**[windows 7] Go to the control panel, "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items" Then find java icon, click on it. Select option "Java" right next to the "General" tab. There is only one button in this box "View", click on this look up your corresponding JRE vesion and make sure it is pointing to the correct version, under path. If your JRE is not visible click ADD.**

My path is C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
javac version 1.7.0_05

Anyone can help me solve this ?

Comment: Does the file `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg` exist?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set your classpath right?
In my case i have set my CLASSPATH to: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib;" 
And JAVA_HOME to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\"

Comment: You don't need CLASSPATH and JAVA_HOME environment variables to run java.