# Why is Git Bash not using the correct Java path as defined in the PATH environment variable?

Tags: java, windows, git-bash

In an instance of Git Bash, typing in `java -version` gives me:

`Error: could not open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\i386\jvm.cfg'`

However, my actual Java path is in `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin`. This is shown in my `%PATH%` variable if I type in either `echo $PATH` or `env | grep PATH`.

Where is Git Bash getting this nonexistent Java path from?

P.S.

To add on to this, running `java -version` in the Command Prompt gives me the correct output:

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What does the %JAVA_HOME% variable contain?

Comment: @RealSkeptic `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\`.  %PATH% really just contains %JAVA_HOME%\bin.

Comment: Could it be that you have an alias for Java somewhere? Try the commands `alias` and `declare -f` in your bash sessions and see if they have anything relating to java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if you have some old `java.exe`, `javaw.exe`, `javaws.exe` in the `c:/windows/system32` folder, as mentioned in "[Java path..Error of `jvm.cfg`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21523980/6309)".

I just checked with [Git 2.6.3 on Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.6.3.windows.1/PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit.7z.exe), where I don't have anything in `c:/windows/system32`, and the result is consistent between:

git bash:

```
vonc@bigvonc MINGW64 /
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

and CMD:

```
C:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit>java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Both report the same java at the same spot:

```
vonc@bigvonc MINGW64 /
$ which java
/c/prgs/jdk/jdk-7u51-windows-x64/bin/java

C:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit>which java.exe
C:\prgs\jdk\jdk-7u51-windows-x64\bin\java.exe
```

Conclusion: **[upgrade to the latest git for windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)**.

Comment: I checked this also -- sorry forgot to mention. `C:/Windows/System32` does not contain any of those `exe`s, apart from a file named `JavaScriptCollectionAgent.dll`.

Comment: @Octopod are the `PATH` or `JAVA_HOME` environment variables somehow different between your CMD session and your git bash session? What git version are you using?

Comment: The two PATH variables are identical aside from the conversion of path separators and such. Git version is `2.5.3.windows.1` according to `git version`. There doesn't seem to be a trace of Java ever being in where Git Bash is telling me it should be. All my environment variables, user and system, don't contain a Java path besides `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: @Octopod would JAVA_HOME differs then? (since the PATH refers to %JAVA_HOME%\bin) Just for testing, would a Git 2.63 (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.6.3.windows.1/PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit.7z.exe: just unzipped anywhere you want) exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: @Octopod Do you have a `$HOME/.bashrc` which might modify things?

Comment: No `.bashrc`. Your provided Git Bash seems to fix the problem -- it gives me the correct Java version. This was a faulty Git for Windows installation on my end perhaps?

Comment: @Octopod That is possible: I always use the archive portable option. I have included that link in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: also it seems Portable Git is the only one that works. I tried installing the latest version and I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to manually set `JDK`, then please check if you haven't missed the `Oracle Java` (`C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`) in `Path` Environment Variable under System Variables, remove it and `java -version` should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `PATH` variable in your `.bash_profile` file to make sure it reflects the correct `version` of `java`. The file is usually in your home directory `C:\Users\\{HOME}\\.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

It will happen when you have running an IDE with another set of JDK instances. The better way to resolve this is set you JDK home in path and make it available in last row. This is working for me.

[image: Windows Env Variable Screen shot]