# apache tomcat not starting after rebooting AWS Ec2 instance

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

we have an instance on AWS server ec2.
we rebooted that instance.
Now our apache server is not starting.
we applied JAVA_HOME and PATH varibale too.

It contain jasper server too.
Its a Windows 64 bit machine

Its giving following warning:

**Warning not found /java/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg**

Comment: What does `JAVA_HOME` have to do with Apache web server? Do you mean Tomcat?

Comment: Yes. I mean Tomcat

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051103/java-path-error-of-jvm-cfg