# Path error when running Java code through my command line

Tags: java, windows, command-line, cmd, path

Every time I try running a Java program through my command line I get this:

```
error(Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg').
```

I'm just learning. This is my code I'm trying to run:

```
class cows2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello Friend");     
    }
}
```

Here is my command line with the error.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You should be using an IDE, Why are you using CMD?

Comment: What happens when you run java —version

Comment: Javac worked, but your Java is pointing to a JRE.

Comment: You can refer the answers from this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051103/java-path-error-of-jvm-cfg