# Eclipse Java Virtual Machine Launcher jvm.cfg Error

Tags: java, eclipse, virtual-machine

Whenever I press RUN in Eclipse, I get this error: "Error: could not open 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg' ".

I tried reinstalling all my Javas and they are all up-to-date.

My installed version JRE is jre1.8.0_66.

[image]

Comment: Post your eclipse.ini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your Eclipse is looking for an older JRE. Look in the Eclipse Preferences 'Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs' and update it to use the path for the update 66 JRE/JDK.

Comment: This worked great once I could run eclipse... I had to reinstall old JRE first

Answer (score 1):

This file is important ([What is the purpose of jvm.cfg file in relation to Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190360/what-is-the-purpose-of-jvm-cfg-file-in-relation-to-java)) and missing it means your installation is corrupted .. you should reinstall it carefully (be sure to choose the right one for your OS/Architecture)

Edit: [Java path..Error of jvm.cfg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051103/java-path-error-of-jvm-cfg), this post might help you; hope you'll fix your issue!