# Java refuses to launch minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft

Whenever I try to launch Minecraft, I get these errors:

```
Warning: No leading - on line 1 of B:\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0-51\amd64\jvm.cfg
Warning: Missing VM type on line 1 of B:\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0-51\amd64\jvm.cfg
Warning: No leading - on line 2 of B:\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0-51\amd64\jvm.cfg
Warning: Missing VM type on line 2 of B:\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0-51\amd64\jvm.cfg
Warning: No leading - on line 3 of B:\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0-51\amd64\jvm.cfg
Warning: Missing VM type on line 3 of B:\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0-51\amd64\jvm.cfg
Error: No known VMs. (Check for corrupt jvm.cfg file)
```

And when I look at the file in question, it it blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check that your java home and java environment variables are pointing to the right version.
2. Open `jvm.cfg` file and specify correct path to `java.home`.

You are hitting the error because your `jvm.cfg` file is blank. 
Take a look at this question for what jvm.cfg is: [What is the purpose of jvm.cfg file in relation to Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190360/what-is-the-purpose-of-jvm-cfg-file-in-relation-to-java)

Comment: Apparently I didn't get the jvm stuff to ever download. Still cant.

Comment: What problem are you getting? Probs better to open a new question if you need help with that.